# Infinite unions of closed sets and infinite intersections of open sets

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

Show by giving an example that for ${F_\iota|\iota\in I}$ an infinte collection of closed sets in $\Bbb R^n$ the set
$$\bigcup_{\iota\in1} F_\iota$$
need not be closed

Deduce that for ${U_\iota|\iota\in I}$ an infinite collection of open sets, the set
$$\bigcap_{\iota\in1} U_\iota$$

need not be open.

Where the sets are indexed by $I$

Comment: Don't You want to deduce that for a collection of open sets $U_{\iota}|\iota \in I$ the intersection $\bigcap_{\iota\in I}U_{\iota}$ need not be open??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $I = \mathbb N$ and
$$F_\iota = \bar{B}(0, 1 - 1/\iota) = \{x \in \mathbb R^n \mid \Vert x \Vert \leq 1-1/\iota\}.$$  Then
$$\bigcup_{\iota \in I}F_\iota = B(0,1) = \{x \in \mathbb R^n \mid \Vert x \Vert <1\},$$
which is not closed. Its complement is 
$$\left(\bigcup_{\iota \in I}F_\iota \right)^c = \bigcap_{\iota \in I}F_\iota^c = B(0,1)^c,$$
so the non-open set $B(0,1)^c$ is an infinite intersection of open sets.

Answer (score 2):

**Any** subset of $\mathbb R^{n}$ is a union of singletons. Not every set is closed. Hence union of closed sets need not be closed.

Comment: This works only for $T_1$ spaces

Comment: @LucasSmits The question is about subsets of $\mathbb R^{n}$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $ \mathbb{R}$:

1) $F_n:= [0,1-1/n]$ is closed.

$ S:=\cup_{n \in \mathbb{Z^+}} F_n$ is not closed;

$1$ is a limit point of $S$, but $1 \not \in S$.

2) $U_n := F_n^c=$

$ (-\infty, 0) \cup (1-1/n,\infty)$ is open.

$T:= \cap_{n \in \mathbb{Z^+}} U_n= \cap_{n \in \mathbb{Z^+}}F_n^c=$

$ (\cup_{n \in \mathbb{Z^+}}F_n)^c$ is not open. (Why?)

($T=(-\infty,0)\cup [1,\infty)$ ).